# Using dispatch_write to write NSData to unique file in background under ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch, nsdata

I am attempting to create a file with a unique name and write data to it in the background.

`mktemp` says `Whenever it is possible, mkstemp() should be used instead, since it does not have the race condition.`

Using `mkstemp` results in an open file descriptor, so `dispatch_write` seems to be obvious.

Now `NSData` must be wrapped in a `dispatch_data_t` using `dispatch_data_create`. Care must be taken to free memory that needs to be freed, and retain memory that must be retained. Under ARC, this is less than obvious.

```
+ (void) createUnique:(NSData*)content name:(NSString*)name
            extension:(NSString*)extension
           completion:(void (^)(NSURL* url, NSError* error))completion {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(
                                       DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_data_t data = dispatch_data_create(content.bytes, content.length,
                                                queue, ^{});
    // dispatch_data_create() copies the buffer if DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT
    // (= NULL) is specified, and attempts to free the buffer if
    // DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_FREE is specified, so an empty destructor is
    // specified.
    dispatch_fd_t descriptor;

    // Ignore details of creating the template C string
    strcpy(nameCString, templateCString);
    descriptor = mkstemps(nameCString, extensionLength);
    free(nameCString);

    if (descriptor != -1) {
        dispatch_write(descriptor, data, queue,
                       ^(dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
                           NSData* strongContent = content;
                           // Will this keep the NSData reference until the
                           // write is finished?

                           if (error) {
                               completion(nil, [NSError
                                                errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain
                                                code:error userInfo:nil]);
                           } else {
                               // Ignore details of getting path from nameCString.
                               completion([NSURL URLWithString:path], nil);
                           }

                           // How does the file get closed?
                       });
    } else {
        completion(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:NSURLErrorDomain code:errno
                                        userInfo:nil]);
    }
}
```

So the questions are:

1. Is this necessary at all? Should `mktemp` be used with `NSData`'s `writeToFile:options:error:` and not worry about security/race conditions?
2. Is the call to `dispatch_data_create` OK with the empty destructor to avoid unnecessary copying (keep a pointer to the `NSData` buffer)?
3. Can the descriptor opened by `mkstemps` be used with `dispatch_write`?
4. Will keeping a reference to the `NSData` keep the `dispatch_data_t` valid? Is this necessary? What is ARC doing here?
5. How is the file closed? `dispatch_io_close`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really what `dispatch_write` (and `dispatch_data` in general) is for. As you've discovered, `dispatch_data` is focused on power and performance, not ease of use. And you have such a simple problem.

Also note that the race condition you're discussing has to do with an active attacker who is rapidly creating files in your temp directory. The attack goes like this:

- You are running as some privileged user. Eve (the attacker) is running an unprivileged user.
- You want to make a temporary file in `/tmp`, which both you and Eve can read and write.
- You look in `/tmp` and see that some filename does not exist
- Before you can create the file, Eve creates the file using exactly the name you just checked. She makes the file world writable (but it's owned by Eve).
- You now open the file and start writing to it, but it's still owned by Eve.
- Now Eve can read and modify your data. This may be translated into a privilege escalation.

This is a real attack on Unix systems. It should be obvious that it is not a real attack on iOS systems. That doesn't mean you shouldn't use `mkstemp`. You should. But it's important to understand what you're protecting against. This isn't a "oops; I collided with myself" race condition unless you're making hundreds of files a second (don't do that).

OK, so how do you do it? Matt Gallagher has a great example in [Cocoa with Love: Temporary files and folders in Cocoa](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html). Copying here for future searchers, but I highly recommend the article:

```
NSString *tempFileTemplate =
    [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myapptempfile.XXXXXX"];
const char *tempFileTemplateCString =
    [tempFileTemplate fileSystemRepresentation];
char *tempFileNameCString = (char *)malloc(strlen(tempFileTemplateCString) + 1);
strcpy(tempFileNameCString, tempFileTemplateCString);
int fileDescriptor = mkstemp(tempFileNameCString);

if (fileDescriptor == -1)
{
    // handle file creation failure
}

// This is the file name if you need to access the file by name, otherwise you can remove
// this line.
tempFileName =
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
        stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:tempFileNameCString
        length:strlen(tempFileNameCString)];

free(tempFileNameCString);
tempFileHandle =
    [[NSFileHandle alloc]
        initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor
        closeOnDealloc:NO];
```

Now, at the end of this, you see that Matt has created both a filename and an `NSFileHandle`. Either is fine to use. You can use `NSData`methods to write to the filename, or you can use `NSFileHandle` write methods. There is no race condition at this point to use the file name, because the file already exists and is owned by you.

To write this in the background, just stick it in a `dispatch_async` block.

Comment: Your post cleared up most of my questions. However, I'm still unsure about the fileDescriptor. If I use `writeToFile:options:error:` with `tempFileName`, the file descriptor remains open. I need to use `close(fileDescriptor)`. I'm hoping that calling `mkstemps()` on the main queue and `close()` on a background queue is OK.

Comment: Yes. You can close a file handle on a different queue.